# Rewrite subdirectory and query_string to a cgi script

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, cgi

Using htaccess I would like the address:

```
mydomain.com/foo?param1=bar
```

to "silently" (i.e., not change the address in the browser bar) rewrite to:

```
mydomain.com/cgi-bin/myscript.cgi?ID=foo&param1=bar
```

Also, I'd like `/foo/?param1=bar` to also behave the same, just in case the trailing slash is entered after foo.

Of course it won't always be foo, and it won't always be param1. So ideally the solution works with any subdirectory, and any `query_string`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achieving this seems pretty easy. Try placing the following code into your htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cgi-bin [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)/?$ /cgi-bin/myscript.cgi?ID=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Comment: Thanks! I added `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` before it so it wouldn't match if it was an existing file/directory. (Hopefully that is correct.) Otherwise it wasn't following existing directories like /images, /css, etc.